# Reshaping image in CNN Image Classification

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

```
IMG_SIZE = 160       # 160x160

def formatting(image, label) :
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)   #convert every pixels to be float32 type
  image = (image / 127.5) - 1 
  image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  return image, label`
```

i understand that image will have to be divided by 255.0 so they will have the range (0-1). But i'm confused why in this case the image is divided by 127.5 which is half of 255 and subtract by 1.

Comment: That is done in order to scale the pixel values into [-1,1] instead of the routine way of devision by 255. The choice between the two methods is case specific.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the image by 127.5 and subtracting 1 is a way to normalize the image data to the range of [-1, 1].

See also this answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54296/should-input-images-be-normalized-to-1-to-1-or-0-to-1